# ConstraintViolationException handler isn't executed in Micronaut

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, micronaut

I have a `ConstraintViolationException` handler class that looks like this:

```
@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {ConstraintViolationException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class ConstraintsViolationsExceptionHandler
        implements ExceptionHandler<ConstraintViolationException, HttpResponse> {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse
    handle(HttpRequest request, ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        return HttpResponse
                .status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                .body(new SignUpPhoneNumberErrorResponse<>(400,
                        "Wrong data used",
                        new ArrayList<>(exception.getConstraintViolations())));
    }
}
```

where `SignUpPhoneNumberErrorResponse` is my error handling POJO which is getting serialized to JSON absolutely fine.

My Controller looks like this:

```
@Controller(PhoneAuthAndLoginConstants.CONTROLLER_BASE_PATH)
@Validated
public class UserPhoneNumberRegistrationAndLoginController {

    @Inject
    MongoDbUserSignUpPhoneNumberDAO mongoDbUserSignUpPhoneNumberDAO;

    @Post(uri = PhoneAuthAndLoginConstants.CONTROLLER_SIGN_UP_PATH,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Single<ResponseDataEncapsulate>
    signUpForPhoneVerification(@Valid @Body UserSignUpPhoneNumberEntity phoneNumber) {
        return mongoDbUserSignUpPhoneNumberDAO.sendVerification(phoneNumber);
    }

    @Post(uri = PhoneAuthAndLoginConstants.CONTROLLER_SIGN_UP_PATH
            +
            PhoneAuthAndLoginConstants.CONTROLLER_SIGN_UP_VERIFICATION_CODE_PARAM,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Single<ResponseDataEncapsulate>
    sendUserSignUpConfirmation(@Valid @Body UserAccountStateSignUpEntity verificationData,
                               HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        return mongoDbUserSignUpPhoneNumberDAO.signUp(verificationData);
    }
}
```

My POJO for `UserAccountStateSignUpEntity` looks like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserAccountStateSignUpEntity implements UserSignUpEntity {
    @NotNull @NotBlank @Size(min = 5, max = 13) private String phoneNumber;
    @NotNull @NotBlank @Size(min = 7, max = 7) private String verificationCode;
    @JsonIgnore private Boolean verifiedAccount = Boolean.FALSE;

    public UserAccountStateSignUpEntity(String phoneNumber, String verificationCode) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
        this.verifiedAccount = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> makePhoneEntityMapForMongo() {
        HashMap<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            put("verificationCode", verificationCode);
            put("verifiedAccount", verifiedAccount);
        }};

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(returnMap);
    }
}
```

I send in a request payload like this:

```
{
    "phoneNumber" : "91-123456789",
    "verificationCode" : "18887"
}
```

This should trigger a `ConstraintViolationException` and my handler code should execute and I should get a HTTP Forbidden. But instead I get the default HTTP Bad Request error message.

**Why isn't my handler getting executed?** 
What can be done to make it execute?

I'm using **Micronaut 1.1.3** as the web framework and the **Hibernate Validator** as the `javax.validation` implementation.

Comment: do you use `io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator` or original `hebernate` dependency ? take a look at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/guide/index.html#datavalidation

Comment: @tsarenkotxt I tried using the `@Introspected` annotation to my POJOs and still no result. And only the `@Introspected` annotation made sense in my case.

Comment: @tsarenkotxt I'm using Micronaut v1.1.3 and the guide that you provided has the `@Inteospected` annotation for v1.2.0.RC1 and not in v1.1.3.

Comment: yes you are right about versions, also I mean dependencies in your classpath, to make sure you add `io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator`

Comment: @tsarenkotxt I already have the required dependencies and that is visible in the logs

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091234/8112217

Comment: @tsarenkotxt Not helpful in my case as the `message` parameter accepts a `String` and the default response is some kind of gibberish structure with the `message` field. I need to send a POJO object with a bunch of other custom fields as well.

Comment: I mean you can try add `message` if it's work you send your custom exception/body with your `SignUpPhoneNumberErrorResponse`,  `message` to trigger validation failure

Comment: Hi Shankha, did you found the solution, if yes could you please share your findings, thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Error that can be applied to method to map it to an error route and SignUpPhoneNumberErrorResponse would be returned as a error response body when any ConstraintViolationException occured.

For more detail visit [Micronaut docs](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#errorHandling)

```
@Controller("/${path}")
@Validated
public class UserPhoneNumberRegistrationAndLoginController {

    @Post
    public HttpResponse method(@Valid @Body UserAccountStateSignUpEntity verificationData, HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        return null;
    }

    @Error(exception = ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public SignUpPhoneNumberErrorResponse onSavedFailed(HttpRequest request, ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        return new SignUpPhoneNumberErrorResponse(500,
                        "Wrong data used",
                        String.valueOf(ex.getConstraintViolations().stream().map( e -> e.getPropertyPath()+": "+e.getMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList())),
                "Application",
                "Error",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Error(status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, global = true)  
    public HttpResponse notFound(HttpRequest request) {
        //return custom 404 error body
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm aware about the `@Error` annotation but it didn't work as well. The only solution that worked for me is the one that I have answered.

Comment: Same @Error didn't work on a separate listener. 
However, it did work for ConstraintViolationException on `@Controller` class (adding to controller class), but then it adds controller method in the failed validation path, e.g. myMethod.someClass.someFiled. It seems `@Error` must be on on `@Controller` to work.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem with error handling in Micronaut. As I figured out, there is not a `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` thrown, but a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`.

For me, then it worked with `@Error(exception = PersistenceException::class)` (Kotlin).

Answer (score 2):

`@Error` annotation handling for `ConstraintViolationException` worked for me only when it is on controller.

In the end managed to handle it like this, by replacing the micronaut `ConstraintExceptionHandler` bean:

```
@Produces
@Replaces(io.micronaut.validation.exceptions.ConstraintExceptionHandler.class)
@Requires(classes = {ConstraintViolationException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class ConstraintExceptionHandler extends io.micronaut.validation.exceptions.ConstraintExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse handle(HttpRequest request, ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        return return HttpResponse
                .badRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there is a way to hook server errors of all type and replace with own implementation facing the issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747492/global-exception-handling-in-micronaut-java

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `@Requires(classes = {ConstraintViolationException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})` annotation and replaced the `ArrayList<>` in the body with a comma separated string and it started to work fine. Although I do not know the consequences of removing the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error here is that Micronaut already defined an exception handler for `ConstraintViolationException` as stated [here](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.3.2/api/io/micronaut/validation/exceptions/ConstraintExceptionHandler.html)

In order to overwrite this one I'd recommend just copying and pasting the definition from the page I linked.

```
@Produces
@Singleton
@Primary
@Requires(classes={javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class,ExceptionHandler.class})
public class ConstraintExceptionHandler
extends java.lang.Object
implements ExceptionHandler<javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException,HttpResponse<JsonError>>
```

(You can fill in the body. The `extends java.lang.Object` is not necessary)

The important part here is that I added the `io.micronaut.context.annotation.Primary` annotation. This will favour your handler over the other defined one. I stole this trick from [ConversionErrorHandler](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.0.1/api/io/micronaut/http/server/exceptions/ConversionErrorHandler.html) because I was running into the same issue as you but with that handler.

Now of course you can change the `HttpResponse<JsonError>` to an `HttpResponse<*>` appropriate for your needs.