# How do I hook into micronaut server on error handling from a filter?

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

For any 4xx or 5xx response given out by my micronaut server, I'd like to log the response status code and endpoint it targeted. It looks like a filter would be a good place for this, but I can't seem to figure out how to plug into the onError handling

for instance, this filter

```
@Filter("/**")
class RequestLoggerFilter: OncePerRequestHttpServerFilter() {
  companion object {
    private val log = LogManager.getLogger(RequestLoggerFilter::class.java)
  }

  override fun doFilterOnce(request: HttpRequest<*>, chain: ServerFilterChain): Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<*>>? {
    return Publishers.then(chain.proceed(request), ResponseLogger(request))
  }

  class ResponseLogger(private val request: HttpRequest<*>): Consumer<MutableHttpResponse<*>> {
    override fun accept(response: MutableHttpResponse<*>) {
      log.info("Status: ${response.status.code} Endpoint: ${request.path}")
    }
  }
}
```

only logs on a successful response and not on 4xx or 5xx responses.
How would i get this to hook into the onError handling?

Comment: Have you looked at the `@Error` annotation (https://docs.micronaut.io/2.0.1/guide/index.html#errorHandling)?

Comment: I did check out the error annotation, and maybe that's the route to go. But if I create a generic error handler that catches Exception then it seems like I lose some nice default error handling that's given for free (like io.micronaut.core.convert.exceptions.ConversionErrorException being turned into a bad request).

Is there a way to have a general error handler perform some logging and then pass off behavior to what would normally occur?

<edit>: I guess what I'd really like is for the regular error handling to occur and then log the final result - 400 to /path

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following. Create your own ApplicationException ( extends RuntimeException), there you could handle your application errors and in particular how they result into http error codes. You exception could hold the status code as well.

Example:

```java
class BadRequestException extends ApplicationException {
 
    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }
}
```

You could have multiple of this ExceptionHandler for different purposes.

```java
@Slf4j
@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {ApplicationException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<ApplicationException, HttpResponse> {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse handle(final HttpRequest request, final ApplicationException exception) {
        log.error("Application exception message={}, cause={}", exception.getMessage(), exception.getCause());
        final String message = exception.getMessage();
        final String code = exception.getClass().getSimpleName();
        final ErrorCode error = new ErrorCode(message, code);

        log.info("Status: ${exception.getStatus())} Endpoint: ${request.path}")

        return HttpResponse.status(exception.getStatus()).body(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to handle Micronaut native exceptions like `400 (Bad Request)` produced by `ConstraintExceptionHandler` you will need to `Replace` the beans to do that.

I've posted example here [how to handle ConstraintExceptionHandler.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702463/2175991)

If you want to only handle responses itself you could use this mapping each response code (example on `@Controller` so not sure if it works elsewhere even with `global flag`:

```
@Error(status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, global = true)  
public HttpResponse notFound(HttpRequest request) {
  <...>
}
```

[Example from Micronaut documentation.](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-error-handling/guide/index.html#globalerror)

Answer (score 0):

Below code I used for adding custom cors headers in the error responses, in `doOnError` you can log errors

```
@Filter("/**")
public class ResponseCORSAdder implements HttpServerFilter {
    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {
            return this.trace(request) 
            .switchMap(aBoolean -> chain.proceed(request))
            .doOnError(error -> {
                if (error instanceof MutableHttpResponse<?>) {
                    MutableHttpResponse<?> res = (MutableHttpResponse<?>) error;
                    addCorsHeaders(res);
                }
            })  
            .doOnNext(res -> addCorsHeaders(res));
    }

        private MutableHttpResponse<?> addCorsHeaders(MutableHttpResponse<?> res) {
            return res
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,POST,GET")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        }

        private Flowable<Boolean> trace(HttpRequest<?> request) {
            return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> { 
                    // trace logic here, potentially performing I/O 
                    return true;
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); 
        }
}
```