# Global exception handler never get called in micronaut 3 with project reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor, micronaut, reactor

After upgrading the micronaut application from 2.5.12 to 3.0.0 and using the Project reactor as reactive stream. The Global exception handler method never get called.

```
 public class GlobalException extends RuntimeException{
        public GlobalException(Throwable throwable){super(throwable);}
    }

@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {GlobalException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<GlobalException, HttpResponse> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public HttpResponse handle(HttpRequest request, GlobalException exception) {
        LOG.error(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOG.error(exception.getCause().getMessage());
        Arrays.stream(exception.getStackTrace()).forEach(item -> LOG.error(item.toString()));
        return HttpResponse.serverError(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

On exception with below code, the handler method never get called

```
@Override
    public Flux<FindProductCommand> get(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria) {
        LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
        return iProductManager.find(searchCriteria).onErrorMap(throwable -> {
            return new GlobalException(throwable);
        });
    }
```

I had this code [Global exception handling in micronaut Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747492/global-exception-handling-in-micronaut-java) from rxjava 3 which was working fine, however, now with project reactor it is not working

Answer (score 1):

If you only intend to produce a single element it should be annotated with `@SingleResult` `Or use Mono`

```
@Override
@SingleResult
public Flux<List<FindProductCommand>> freeTextSearch(String text) {
    LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
    return iProductManager.findFreeText(text)
            .onErrorMap(throwable -> {
                throw new GlobalException(throwable);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@Override
    public Flux<FindProductCommand> get(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria) {
        LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
        return iProductManager
                  .find(searchCriteria)
                  .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new GlobalException("My exception", e));
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this might be that in your code, looking at this bit:

```java
@Override
public Flux<FindProductCommand> get(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria) {
    LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
    return iProductManager.find(searchCriteria).onErrorMap(throwable -> {
        return new GlobalException(throwable);
    });
}
```

If the code `iProductManager.find(searchCriteria)` is calling a rest endpoint and getting a 404 not found, you will not get an error in the error handler. Rather the result is that you will get the equivalent of an `Optional.empty()`.

If you want to force en error, you could change it to something like:

`iProductManager.find(searchCriteria).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(...))`